# CSS Image replacement technique repeats the image

Tags: html, css

I have this site

https://preview.c9.io/pgonzalez/demo-project/html/test.html?_c9_id=livepreview0&_c9_host=https://ide.c9.io

The logo at the top is an image, I'm using this technique

```
 h1{
            position:relative;
        }
        span{
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            position:absolute;
            background-image:url(Images/headertext.png);
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }
     </style>
 </head>
 <body>
    <header>
        <h2>
        <span></span>
        The rainy season
        </h2>
    </header>
```

and it works as I expect. However, the same technique doesn't work here

https://demo-project-c9-pgonzalez.c9.io/html/API.html

You will see how the background image shows twice and in a completely different position, the code I'm using is the same

```
h1 {
position: relative;
}

span {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
position: absolute;
background-image: url(Images/headertext.png);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
```

Can't figure out what is causing this. Thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because there is another span on the page.

You want:

```
h1 span {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background-image: url(Images/headertext.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

And probably want to reference it more specific than that. You CSS will add that background to ANY `span` on the page. What I posted above will only affect `span`s that are children of `h1` tags.

Comment: So that removed the repeated images but now it's only showing half the image.....going through it now see if I can figure it out.

Comment: The reason it doesn't display the entire image is because it's a BG image. So it's going to set the background of the space to the image you select. The space is smaller than the background image so it's only showing part of the image. Your image is 232 x 72. Set the h1 width/height to 232 x 72 and make it `display: block;`. Why use text at all. Why not just use a `img`.

Comment: Spot on, I can take it from here. Thanks.

Comment: It was just a section of the CSS Cookbook so I wanted to test it out but yeah, it's not something I'd use in this particular scenario.

Answer (score 0):

This is because one page header is defined as such, which doesn't work:

```
        #headertest{
            position:absolute;
            width:100%;
            height:100%;
            background-image:url(../Images/developerstitle.png);
            background-repeat:no-repeat;
        }
```

And on the other page that this technique does works is defined as:

```
        header{
            color:white;
            background-color:black;
            padding:10px;
            text-align:center;
            background-image:url(Images/headerbackground.jpg);
            background-attachment:fixed;
            background-position:center;
        }
```

My guess is that the Position statement must be changed/removed.

Comment: It was a problem with the h1 height and width. See the answer above, but thanks for sharing!